CDAP custom plugin icon not appearing in CDAP UI even after successful registration
I have created a custom plugin where I need to perform crud operations in MySQL Database. But CDAP custom plugin icon is not appearing in CDAP UI even after successful registration of the plugin. I'm attaching the source code , POM and plugin-config JSON file.
package com.sixdee.sinks;

import io.cdap.cdap.api.annotation.Description;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.annotation.Macro;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.annotation.Name;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.annotation.Plugin;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.plugin.PluginConfig;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.data.format.StructuredRecord;
import io.cdap.cdap.api.data.schema.Schema;
import io.cdap.cdap.etl.api.batch.BatchSink;
import io.cdap.cdap.etl.api.batch.BatchSinkContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Plugin(type = BatchSink.PLUGIN_TYPE)
@Name("CustomMysqlSink")
@Description("Custom database sink plugin to perform insert, update, and delete operations.")
public class CustomDatabaseSink extends BatchSink<StructuredRecord, Void, Void> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomDatabaseSink.class);
    private final DatabaseSinkConfig config;

    public CustomDatabaseSink(DatabaseSinkConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public static class DatabaseSinkConfig extends PluginConfig {
        @Description("The JDBC connection string including database name")
        @Macro
        private String connectionString;

        @Description("The database username")
        @Macro
        private String username;

        @Description("The database password")
        @Macro
        private String password;

        @Description("The database table name")
        @Macro
        private String tableName;

        @Description("The type of operation to perform (insert, update, delete)")
        @Macro
        private String operationType;

        @Description("The logical operator to use in the WHERE condition (AND, OR)")
        @Macro
        private String logicalOperator;

        @Description("The schema field names used in the SET clause, comma-separated")
        @Macro
        private String setFields;

        @Description("The schema field names used in the WHERE clause, comma-separated")
        @Macro
        private String whereFields;

        public String getConnectionString() {
            return connectionString;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public String getTableName() {
            return tableName;
        }

        public String getOperationType() {
            return operationType;
        }

        public String getLogicalOperator() {
            return logicalOperator;
        }

        public String getSetFields() {
            return setFields;
        }

        public String getWhereFields() {
            return whereFields;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareRun(BatchSinkContext context) {
        // Implement necessary setup, if required
    }

    public void transform(StructuredRecord input) {
        // Perform the database operation (insert, update, delete) here
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                config.getConnectionString(), config.getUsername(), config.getPassword())) {
            String operationType = config.getOperationType();
            String sql = generateSQL(input, operationType);

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                setParameters(stmt, input, operationType);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error("Error executing SQL operation", e);
        }
    }

    private String generateSQL(StructuredRecord input, String operationType) {
        String tableName = config.getTableName();
        List<Schema.Field> setFields = getFieldsFromSchema(input.getSchema(), config.getSetFields());
        List<Schema.Field> whereFields = getFieldsFromSchema(input.getSchema(), config.getWhereFields());

        String setClause = setFields.stream()
                .map(f -> f.getName() + " = ?")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String whereClause = whereFields.stream()
                .map(f -> f.getName() + " = ?")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" " + config.getLogicalOperator() + " "));

        switch (operationType.toLowerCase()) {
            case "insert":
                return String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", tableName,
                        setFields.stream().map(Schema.Field::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")),
                        setFields.stream().map(f -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
            case "update":
                return String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s", tableName, setClause, whereClause);
            case "delete":
                return String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s", tableName, whereClause);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported operation type: " + operationType);
        }
    }

    private List<Schema.Field> getFieldsFromSchema(Schema schema, String fieldNames) {
        return schema.getFields().stream()
                .filter(f -> fieldNames.contains(f.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private void setParameters(PreparedStatement stmt, StructuredRecord input, String operationType) throws SQLException {
        int index = 1;
        List<Schema.Field> setFields = getFieldsFromSchema(input.getSchema(), config.getSetFields());
        List<Schema.Field> whereFields = getFieldsFromSchema(input.getSchema(), config.getWhereFields());

        for (Schema.Field field : setFields) {
            Object value = input.get(field.getName());
            stmt.setObject(index++, value);
        }

        // Set parameters for WHERE clause if necessary
        if ("update".equalsIgnoreCase(operationType) || "delete".equalsIgnoreCase(operationType)) {
            for (Schema.Field field : whereFields) {
                Object value = input.get(field.getName());
                stmt.setObject(index++, value);
            }
        }
    }
}


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sixdee</groupId>
<name>CustomMysqlSink</name>
<artifactId>Custom-Mysql-Sink</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
<cdap.version>6.10.0</cdap.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>3.11.2</mockito.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>cdap-release</id>
<url>https://repository.cdap.io/repo/releases</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>cdap-snapshot</id>
<url>https://repository.cdap.io/repo/snapshots</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
<artifactId>cdap-api</artifactId>
<version>${cdap.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
<artifactId>cdap-etl-api</artifactId>
<version>${cdap.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>



<!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
 
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
            <Bundle-Version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</Bundle-Version>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>


</project>

{
  "properties": {
      "name": "Custom-Mysql-Sink",
       "type": "sink",
       "description": "Custom MySQL Sink Plugin",
       "widgets.CustomMysqlSink-batchsink": "{\n  \"outputs\": [],\n  \"jump-config\": {\"datasets\": [{\"ref-property-name\": \"referenceName\"}]},\n  \"metadata\": {\"spec-version\": \"1.5\"},\n  \"configuration-groups\": [\n    {\n      \"label\": \"Connection\",\n      \"properties\": [\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"toggle\",\n          \"name\": \"useConnection\",\n          \"label\": \"Use connection\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"default\": \"false\",\n            \"off\": {\n              \"label\": \"NO\",\n              \"value\": \"false\"\n            },\n            \"on\": {\n              \"label\": \"YES\",\n              \"value\": \"true\"\n            }\n          }\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"connection-select\",\n          \"name\": \"connection\",\n          \"label\": \"Connection\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"connectionType\": \"MySQL\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"plugin-list\",\n          \"name\": \"jdbcPluginName\",\n          \"label\": \"JDBC Driver name\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"plugin-type\": \"jdbc\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"host\",\n          \"label\": \"Host\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"default\": \"localhost\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"number\",\n          \"name\": \"port\",\n          \"label\": \"Port\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"default\": \"3306\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"user\",\n          \"label\": \"Username\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"password\",\n          \"name\": \"password\",\n          \"label\": \"Password\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"keyvalue\",\n          \"name\": \"connectionArguments\",\n          \"label\": \"Connection Arguments\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"kv-delimiter\": \"=\",\n            \"key-placeholder\": \"Key\",\n            \"value-placeholder\": \"Value\",\n            \"delimiter\": \";\",\n            \"showDelimiter\": \"false\"\n          }\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"label\": \"Basic\",\n      \"properties\": [\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"referenceName\",\n          \"label\": \"Reference Name\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"placeholder\": \"Name used to identify this sink for lineage. Typically, the name of the table/view.\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"database\",\n          \"label\": \"Database\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"connection-browser\",\n          \"widget-category\": \"plugin\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"label\": \"Browse Database\",\n            \"connectionType\": \"MySQL\"\n          }\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"tableName\",\n          \"label\": \"Table Name\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"LogicalOperator\",\n          \"label\": \"Logical Operator\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"OperationType\",\n          \"label\": \"Operation Type\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\"default\": \"insert\"}\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"SetFields\",\n          \"label\": \"Set Fields\"\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"WhereFields\",\n          \"label\": \"where Fields\"\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"label\": \"SSL\",\n      \"properties\": [\n        {\n          \"name\": \"useSSL\",\n          \"widget-type\": \"select\",\n          \"label\": \"Use SSL\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"default\": \"If available\",\n            \"values\": [\n              \"If available\",\n              \"Yes\",\n              \"No\"\n            ]\n          }\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl\",\n          \"label\": \"Keystore URL\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"password\",\n          \"name\": \"clientCertificateKeyStorePassword\",\n          \"label\": \"Keystore Password\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl\",\n          \"label\": \"Truststore URL\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"password\",\n          \"name\": \"trustCertificateKeyStorePassword\",\n          \"label\": \"Truststore Password\"\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"label\": \"Advanced\",\n      \"properties\": [\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"toggle\",\n          \"name\": \"useCompression\",\n          \"label\": \"Use Compression\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"default\": \"false\",\n            \"off\": {\n              \"label\": \"No\",\n              \"value\": \"false\"\n            },\n            \"on\": {\n              \"label\": \"Yes\",\n              \"value\": \"true\"\n            }\n          }\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"textbox\",\n          \"name\": \"sqlMode\",\n          \"label\": \"SQL_MODE\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"widget-type\": \"toggle\",\n          \"name\": \"autoReconnect\",\n          \"label\": \"Auto Reconnect\",\n          \"widget-attributes\": {\n            \"default\": \"false\",\n            \"off\": {\n              \"label\": \"No\",\n              \"value\": \"false\"\n            },\n            \"on\": {\n              \"label\": \"Yes\",\n              \"value\": \"true\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  ],\n  \"display-name\": \"CustomMySQL\",\n  \"type\": \"sink\",\n  \"icon\": {\n    \"arguments\": {\"data\": \"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAxCAYAAACYq/ofAAADXElEQVR4nN1ZPWzTQBT+zolbJCT+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\\r\\nRK5C\"},\n    \"type\": \"inline\"\n  },\n  \"filters\": [\n    {\n      \"condition\": {\"expression\": \"useConnection == false\"},\n      \"name\": \"showConnectionProperties \",\n      \"show\": [\n        {\n          \"name\": \"jdbcPluginName\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"user\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"password\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"host\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"port\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"connectionArguments\",\n          \"type\": \"property\"\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"condition\": {\"expression\": \"useConnection == true\"},\n      \"name\": \"showConnectionId\",\n      \"show\": [{\n        \"name\": \"connection\",\n        \"type\": \"property\"\n      }]\n    }\n  ]\n}"
     },
  "parents": [
    "system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.9.0-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)",
    "system:cdap-data-streams[6.9.0-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)"
  ]
}

I have build the custom jar and JSON file successfully and uploaded to CDAP successfully but the icon is not visible in CDAP UI.
Custom-Mysql-Sink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Custom-Mysql-Sink-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.json
I want to have the icon in sink

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
